# SVN / Tortoise SVN - Cannot checkout, Access is denied

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, checkout

We are having a strange problem with our SVN repository

One particular project is failing to check out on some dev's workstations.

The error is:

> svn: E720005: Can't open file
>   'C:\path\.svn\pristine\4e\4e576fad0f625706379863e6051aac33097dbee0.svn-base':
>   Access is denied.

All branches, tags and trunk fail at the same point of checkout

Other projects in the repository can be checked out fine

One of our devs can check out the problem project fine.

We have tried 3 different versions of TortoiseSVN (both UI and command line) and another build of win32svn.

The one who can check out is using the same client version as one who cannot.

Any ideas?

Comment: User permissions on the server (that is, different for the user who can checkout versus those who can't)?

Comment: Turned out to be a false-positive from Sophos - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be Anti Virus software

There is a false positive issue at present: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/09/19/sshupdater-b-fsophos-anti-virus-products/

The file which was failing to checkout was called `Project.Updater.exe`

Temporarily disabling Sophos On Access Scanning allowed the project checkout succeeds

Our Service Desk is updating the Sophos IDEs